# How to animate 3d spheres in matplotlib so that they revolve around a central point?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation, 3d

I'm trying to create an animated 3d model of the solar system with accurate sizes and velocities of the planets in matplotlib without using vpython. I have the starting locations and models of the planets down, but when it comes to animation, I'm completely lost.

I tried looking at some animation tutorials but they either
1. Make the planets revolve using vpython or
2. Show animation in matplotlib but nothing concerning revolving around a specific point.

In the code I have included just the sun and mercury. If someone could demonstrate mercury revolving around the sun in 3d matplotlib animation (perhaps using FuncAnimation?) that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as ani
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import math

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
c1=1000

ax.set_xlim(-1300000000,1300000000)
ax.set_ylim(-1300000000,1300000000)
ax.set_zlim(-1300000000,1300000000)

#sun
rs=10000*c1
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
xs = rs*np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
ys = rs*np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
zs = rs*np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
sun=ax.plot_surface(xs, ys, zs,  rstride=4, cstride=4, color='y')


#mercury
dmer=57900000
rmer=2440*c1
xmer=rmer*np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v)) +dmer
ymer=rmer*np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
zmer=rmer*np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
mercury=ax.plot_surface(xmer, ymer, zmer,  rstride=4, cstride=4, color='r')

plt.show()
```